# 2 circuits with different power sources

Tags: voltage, communication, ground

First of all, I know very little about electronics, so my question may seem very stupid.

I have 2 circuits, both have a microcontroller but they have a different power source (both powered by USB, but from a different source). The first circuit should be able to output an analog signal (0-5V) to the other circuit but of course they don't share the same GND so that doesn't work "out of the box". The analog signal comes from a DAC ([MCP-4725](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/mcp4725.pdf)).

What's the best/simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't they share the same ground if they are both derived from USB power?

Comment: They're powered by a different device.

Comment: Is there any reason why the two devices grounds can't be connected together? it is very rarely necessary for the ground of one or both devices to 'float'

Comment: @Icy no reason, just didn't think of it. I didn't know it was even possible to just connect two different grounds together.

Comment: This is sort of the "crux" of serial comm. if you have two devices referenced to potentially different grounds, you need to use some kind of isolation to prevent ground loops. A differential pair is a good way to accomplish this.. Something like RS485. You can transmit analog values using digital information that is reconstructed on the receiving end.

Comment: While the question is indeed basic, you were right to ask. Often enough, people with limited knowledge in electronics just assume they can connect things together, then come here asking why their board smoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However are they connected, just add another wire which connects one board's "ground" to the other boards "ground". It's that simple! Your DAC signal probably goes through a wire and into the other board, so along with that wire do this:

Attach (solder, screw terminal, whatever) another wire on the first board to GND, twist that along with the DAC signal wire so they form a twisted pair (this helps shield the DAC wire too which is handy) and at the second board where the DAC wire goes, find the closest GND point and solder/attach the wire there.

This means they both know what "0V" is, with reference to each others supply.

Without a common ground, the board with the DAC output will be sending for example: 1V with reference to board 1's ground reference. The second board won't know what 1V means in the context of a ground reference, and it will cause incorrect results. By connecting the two Grounds together, they will both become 0V, and the second board will be able to read 1V with reference to the common ground (0V) without issue.

edit: As some others have hinted, multiple power sources may not always safely be joined in this way, especially if the supplies are using fancy grounding techniques, split supplies, or one is grounded at mains and the other is not. If you have a virtual ground in one device, joining it to a true ground in another device will blow things up. If one device is properly grounded/earthed and another is not, the wire joining them may short out if there is a ground fault in the AC circuit of the non-grounded one. I am not 100% certain on the AC side of things, as I mostly deal with DC circuits in my line of work.

Comment: I think I'm going to buy "Electronics for dummies". I've got a lot to learn :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While connecting the grouds is ideed the right solution in this case, I'd like to point out that connecting two potentials from different electronic devices is not always safe. In your case, both devices are powered by USB adapters, which typically have the appliance class 2 symbol on them:

[image]

The implication is that low-voltage circuit is insulated from mains potential, so you can connect any potential from one device to any potential of another device without the risk of having mains-rated voltage in between. In case of some [simple power supplies](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21403/how-can-i-increase-the-output-current-in-a-transformerless-power-supply), connecting two devices like that has a high chance of a big blue spark popping out.