# Designing small size AC/DC to provide 3.3 V for MCU

Tags: power-supply, esp8266, transformerless

I have designed ESP8266 based light switch, that is controllable via web page or a push button. Light is being switched with use of Triac (TIC206) through optocoupler ([MOC3041](http://kubuntu.free.fr/wiki/data/fp/moc3041.pdf)). Prototype works as intended. This is the concept:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faa9If.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now I need the advice on the power supply design. As it needs to fit into a quite a small case, the whole circuit needs to be small. I was considering the transformerless design, but it seems that most of designs are for lower currents.

MCU can draw around [200 mA](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=133). MOC3041 seems to require up to additional 60 mA.

I found some full bridge [designs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21403/how-can-i-increase-the-output-current-in-a-transformerless-power-supply) that claim to provide around 200mA but I am not sure if they are suitable for this purpose.

So basically I need 220V AC to 3.3V DC ~200 mA power supply, that is:

- small
- not dissipating a lot of heat (small case)
- stable in 24/7 operation
- not very expensive

What would you recommend?

Comment: Start by taking a look at one of my questions as well as answers and discussion here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/252067/reducing-volume-for-a-split-phase-230vac60hz-sealed-power-supply-providing-5vdc

Answer (score 1):

Your need for \$200\:\textrm{mA}\$ does place a special burden. This means getting near a full watt of power. Monolithic Power's MP103 might have been an option, if you were looking for a little less current compliance. But it doesn't get even to half of what you are looking for.

Please do take a complete look at the [EE.SE link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/252067/reducing-volume-for-a-split-phase-230vac60hz-sealed-power-supply-providing-5vdc) for a question I asked, earlier this year. There are some interesting possibilities from that. One of them was an enclosed AC DC Converter providing \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ and up to \$800\:\textrm{mA}\$ from a VAC input up to \$264\:\textrm{V}_\textrm{AC}\$. The Digikey link to a \$3.3\:\textrm{V}\$ rated unit from the same manufacturer is [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?keywords=%20%09945-2253-ND%20) and also [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/recom-power/RAC02-3.3SE-277-W/945-2281-ND/5226215). Either provides more current compliance than you need. And neither is exactly cheap. But the more expensive one is for household use and has all those nice ratings and approvals you may want. May be worth the extra to you. The other module also looks nice. (My EE.SE question has additional thoughts, though. So peruse it and see what you think.)

Answer (score 1):

A series capacitor supply on 230 VAC will give ~~~~= 10 mA per uF.
The capacitor **MUST** be Y or X rated at 230 VAC and
the circuit **MUST** be treated as if all parts are at full mains voltage.

At say 5V x 250 mA that's a (much too) LARGE capacitor.

A possible way to reduce volume is to produce a higher DC voltage and use a buck converter to convert it to 5V or whatever else is wanted.
If you made say 25 VDC and then converted to say 5 VDC the series capacitor can reduce by a factor of 5 times. So say 25V x 50 mA needs ~= 5 uF which MAY be doable.   50VDC needs only about 2.5 uF which is getting nicely doable, but 50V converter ICs are rare - but an external switch would handle this with ease. The buck converter can be 'tiny'.

Comment: These are interesting but bit bigger than what I hoped for. Now I am considering SMPS. A 2$ Chinese USB charger that I am using for prototype is just a bit bigger than those solutions and it takes around 30% of space for USB connector. I can spread SMPS components with rest of my PCB components. However a problem for me is understanding important parts of the design and getting parts (specially transformer). Where do you get transformers this small - without winding them by hand?

Comment: @Marko SMPS transformers are almost all custom, with a few types produced to evaluate specific SMPS chips, but at high prices. You would save money (though perhaps not safely) in small quantities by salvaging them from an inexpensive flyback converter. In higher quantities (thousands and up), design your transformer with *everything* specified and send it to manufacturers for quotation.

Comment: @Sphero Pefhany I was hoping it is possible to get those at least from suppliers for the repair shops or someone like this. I am hobbyist trying to design something and learn in the process, so I only want to make few of these. If nothing else helps I will try your advice with salvaging from converters.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a ready made supply. You will not get the current you need from a capacitor supply and still keep the size small. If you are patient you can get cheap supplies from China. You can't get the cost as low as a delivered module.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/AC-DC-Switching-Power-Supply-110V-220V-to-3-3V-700mA-Buck-Converter-Regulated/32667323655.html

Comment: @Marko if buying commercial supplies like these at this sort of price pay GREAT attention to input - output isolation OR assume that they are non isolated (which they may be regardless).